# Outlook authentication (SSO) with O365 via SAML as IDP Protocol - Invalid Resource error

Tags: oauth, outlook, office365, single-sign-on, saml

We want to login into Office 365 with the Outlook 365 Desktop Clients using Single Sign-On with an own Identity Provider using SAML assertions.
The whole workflow including creating a SAMLResponse seems to work, but if the SAMLResponse is sent to https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf we receive an error message like:

```
<form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="ms-appx-web://Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin/d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c"><input type="hidden" name="error" value="invalid_resource" />

   <input type="hidden" name="error_description" value="AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://dev-o365-vk.xxxxxxxx.com/ was not found in the tenant named 1742xxd3-07xx-xxxx-xxxx-7f5d28986xx3. 
   This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
   Trace ID: 67faxx5-bbf7-4dd4-8d52-xxxxx
   Correlation ID: 13xxe9f1-350b-40fd-bd6b-xxxxx
   Timestamp: 2019-07-09 12:06:04Z" />
```

We see a similar error message in the Azure Portal.
This whole single-sign-on-Setup works, if we login to Office 365 via a web browser.

We did not install any application in the azure portal because Outlook Desktop client should be a standard app with a fixed id (d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c) and should be known to Azure. 
But we are unaware whether creating a suitable Application is necessary nonetheless.
If so, how would we create/install such an application in the azure portal?
Or what else may be missing in the configuration so that Office 365/Azure get to know the resource principal (https://dev-o365-vk.xxxxxxxx.com/  in the error message above) ?